# 'Eigen_solver_traits' does not name a type?

Tags: c++, typedef, eigen, cgal, surface

I am attempting to use the example CGAL Surface Reconstruction code as detailed [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/Surface_reconstruction_points_3_2poisson_reconstruction_example_8cpp-example.html), yet when I try to use this line of code:

```
Poisson_reconstruction_function function(points.begin(), points.end(),CGAL::make_normal_of_point_with_normal_pmap(PointList::value_type()) );
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h: In member function ‘bool CGAL::Poisson_reconstruction_function<Gt>::compute_implicit_function(bool)’:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Poisson_reconstruction_function.h:537:13: error: ‘Eigen_solver_traits’ does not name a type
 typedef Eigen_solver_traits<Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen_sparse_symmetric_matrix<double>::EigenType> > Solver;
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Because there's a bug in CGAL? Questions like this belong on the library's mailing list, not SO.

Answer (score 1):

This particular error usually means you need to add a `typename`. Try

```
typedef typename Eigen_solver_traits<Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen_sparse_symmetric_matrix<double>::EigenType> > Solver;
        ^^^^^^^^
```

or perhaps,

```
typedef Eigen_solver_traits<Eigen::ConjugateGradient<typename Eigen_sparse_symmetric_matrix<double>::EigenType> > Solver;
                                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, fixed it by ensuring CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED was enabled. Thanks again however for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

When using cmake, add the following lines to your CMakeLists file:

`find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR} )`